# ASP.NET space in query parameter value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET WebAPI controller action with the following signature:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFoo(string something=null)
```

When this is called with the following query string: `GetFoo?something=%20` I expect that the action is invoked with: `something = " "` but instead, something is set to null.

How can I make the controller action accept `%20` as a string with a single space and pass it on to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very surprising, but you're right. It seems that MVC parses out a single space in route values.

I have a solution for you, but it's more a work-around than an actual answer.

Add this class:

```
public sealed class AllowSingleSpaceAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _routeValueName;

    public AllowSingleSpaceAttribute(string valueName)
    {
        _routeValueName = valueName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

        if (context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(_routeValueName))
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Query[_routeValueName] == " ")
            {
                context.ActionArguments[_routeValueName] = " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then decorate your controller like this:

```
[AllowSingleSpace("something")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFoo(string something=null)
{
    ...
}
```

You'll get what you're looking for, but it smells! I'd love to understand the reason this happens.

Comment: Thanks! Also found that the value is populated correctly if I get it trough `Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()`

Comment: Code needs `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;`